# SQL Server Linked Server RPC Options?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, rpc

When setting up a linked server in SQL Server (we're on 2005), you can set two server options:

- Rpc
- Rpc Out

Looking at the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186839.aspx), all it states is:

> RPC - Enables RPC from the specified
>   server.
>
> RPC Out - Enables RPC to the specified
>   server.

My question is, why would I need to set these options? What can I do / not do by enabling Rpc on a linked server? Does setting these options to true have any drawbacks?

**EDIT:**

But to execute the remote stored procedure, you'd need the "RPC Out" setting enabled. When would you ever need the "RPC" setting enabled?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An example of an RPC in this context is a stored procedure. To link another server and run an sp on it you'll need to set the RPC Out option.

-Anders

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand now that you need RPC Out enabled to execute a stored procedure on the linked server. Why would you ever need RPC enabled though? Why would you go through a linked server to execute a local procedure? Or am I missing something?

Comment: There are many times when you may want to execute a stored procedure on a remote server.  If you needed to make a bunch of changes to a remote database as part of a load process, executing a remote stored procedure would be the best method.

Comment: But to execute the remote stored procedure, you'd need the "RPC Out" setting enabled. When would you ever need the "RPC" setting enabled?

Comment: When the linked server is more like a partnership than a client/server relationship.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but it returns as one of the first links on a search. I am just adding to @chankster answer to give a bit more detail and when to use it. I don't have enough rep. to post it as a comment yet. Same answer I gave on https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/107042/70662. According to a [msdn blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jason_howell/archive/2014/10/01/what-is-the-rpc-and-rpc-out-option-on-a-sql-server-linked-server.aspx) the RPC vs RPC Out on a SQL Server linked-server is this:

1. RPC - This setting is mainly for legacy feature called [Remote Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190187.aspx). According to the blog it states you will not be using this in SQL Server 2005 and higher. Unless you get an error like:

> 18482 “Could not connect to server '%.*ls' because '%.*ls' is not defined as a remote server. Verify that you have specified the correct server name. %.*ls.”

2. RPC Out - setting is very pertinent to linked servers on SQL Server 2005 and higher. If this is not enabled you can get the following error message:

> Msg 7411, Level 16, State 1, Line 1  Server 'myLinkedServer' is not configured for RPC.

Which really should say **RPC *Out*** should be enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I came across this information below. RPC really doesn't do anything. You just need RPC OUT enabled.

[***external link to the information I found***](http://msgroups.net/microsoft.public.sqlserver.server/rpc-vs-rpc-out-for-linked-s/98628)